# Does the Genie live in your vessel?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

It's not mentioned anywhere, but I suppose having your Genie appear from the lamp whenever he wants could give your campaign some extra flavour.

Comment: This question would be improved if you add more information about Warlock class feature you are referring to (the [Genie pact](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/warlock:the-genie), it seems).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, they don't (the vessel is for you).

The text technically doesn't prohibit it, but there's also not much that supports it. It mentions the size and furnishings of the vessel and while the absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence, it would be a glaring omission if the genie lived in the vessel and they simply didn't mention it.

> As an action, you can magically vanish and enter your vessel, which remains in the space you left. The interior of the vessel is an extradimensional space in the shape of a 20-foot-radius cylinder, 20 feet high, and resembles your vessel. The interior is appointed with cushions and low tables and is a comfortable temperature. [...]

While you are able to speak with the vessel, it seems to be much more of a means of communication rather than functioning because the genie is inside the vessel.

> At 14th level, you entreat your patron to grant you a small wish. As an action, you can speak your desire to your Genie's Vessel, [...]

The vessel itself is not bound to your patron: it's bound to *you*. If you die, the vessel vanishes, and your patron can simply replace it — if they inhabited the vessel, it's unlikely that it would be such a trivial matter.

> If the vessel is destroyed or you lose it, you can perform a 1-hour ceremony to receive a replacement from your patron. This ceremony can be performed during a short or long rest, and the previous vessel is destroyed if it still exists. The vessel vanishes in a flare of elemental power when you die.

While it's possible that the genie could choose to visit your vessel by DM fiat (there aren't many rules guiding how patrons will or should behave, but a noble genie can "wield power that rivals that of lesser deities"), there's nothing that indicates they *live* in the vessel. The vessel is yours to inhabit and carry around. Additionally, a given patron may have pacts with multiple warlocks, at which point any given vessel would be at most a timeshare.

Comment: What sourcebook is this Genie's Vessel from?

Comment: Warlock Pact option published in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything